# Cisco - redistribute prefix

Tags: cisco, bgp

I had 2 C class IP's: xx.xx.xx.0/23.

I must advertise it on BGP protocol. My config is:

> ip route xx.xx.xx.0 255.255.254.0 Null0
>   !
>   access-list 50 permit xx.xx.xx.0 0.0.1.255
>   !
>   route-map RIPE permit 10
>   match ip address 50
>   set origin igp
>   !
>   router bgp YYYYY
>   network xx.xx.xx.0 mask 255.255.254.0
>   redistribute static route-map RIPE
>   ....
>   no auto-summary

OK, that works, but I need to move subnet of my prefix to gateway into my network:

ip route xx.xx.xx.8 255.255.255.248 xx.xx.xx.123
ip route xx.xx.xx.16 255.255.255.240 xx.xx.xx.122

How I can prevent distribute /29 and /28 ? I should distribute only /23

RO: sh ip bgp route-map RIPE

BGP table version is 9203492, local router ID is 192.168.14.1
Status codes: s suppressed, d damped, h history, * valid, > best, i - internal,
              r RIB-failure, S Stale
Origin codes: i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete

   Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
*> xx.xx.xx.0/23  0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
*> xx.xx.xx.8/29  xx.xx.xx.123             0         32768 i
*> xx.xx.xx.16/28 xx.xx.xx.132             0         32768 i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a prefix-list instead of the straight ACL.  Check out [this description](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_2/iproute/command/reference/1rfbgp1.html#wp1215231), set it to an exact-match of the /23 and then match on it in your route-map.  The longer prefixes won't be permitted.